# How do I import this file of data in Python?

Tags: python, text-files

So I just started with Python and I have no idea how to import the text file the way I want it to.

This is my code so far:

```
f = open("Data.txt", "r")
attributes = f.readlines()

w1 = 2 * np.random.random((1,19)) -1

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

outputs = sigmoid(np.dot(attributes, w1))
```

So the problem here is that I get the error message:

```
Cannot cast array data from dtype('float64') to dtype('<U32') according to the rule 'safe'.
```

I know that the problem is that the code does not read the text file as an array of numbers which is why I get the error.

This is one line in the text file:

```
1,1,22,22,22,19,18,14,49.895756,17.775994,5.27092,0.771761,0.018632,0.006864,0.003923,0.003923,0.486903,0.100025,1,0
```

Comment: "This is one line in the text file:" Okay, and what is the logic for how the data in the text file should be stored into an array?

Comment: What is the shape of `attributes` supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there :

```
import numpy as np
with open("Data.txt", "r") as f:
    attributes = f.readlines()
attributes = [row.strip().split(",") for row in attributes]
attributes = [[float(x) for x in row] for row in attributes]

w1 = 2 * np.random.random((1,20)) -1

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

outputs = sigmoid(np.dot(np.array(attributes), w1.T))
```

You needed something like "list comprehension" to split values on each row (if there are more than one). Also, you were missing one element in w1 to match the dimension of attributes. And finally, you will have to use the transposition of w1 to make the production using np.dot (np.array(attributes)'s shape is (1,20) as well as w1's.

Also : always remember to use this "with" statement to open files (it automatically close the file after ending the statement ; otherwise, you might get into some trouble...)

---

**Edit**

If your real dataset contains more data, you should consider the use of pandas, which will be much more efficient :

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("Data.txt"), sep=",", header=None)
numpy_array = df.values
```

Comment: Alright, so now I got the errormessage: ValueError: shapes (1151,20) and (1,20) not aligned: 20 (dim 1) != 1 (dim 0). What's the problem now?

Comment: Drop the ".T". To make a product of vectors, you need a shapes of (X,Y) * (Y,Z) : that's pure maths. (You can access the shape of a numpy array using my_array.shape.). But if your real dataset is 20*1551 , I'll edit my answer to make you discover the pandas module.

Comment: Okey so, now another error occurs. TypeError: parser_f() got an unexpected keyword argument 'spe'

Comment: This seems to be another question in fact. It is about your file not formatted adequatly. Maybe a coma being put inside a string field. Is it not all numbers in that file ?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I made a typo. That's "sep", not "spe"...

Comment: Okey, thanks. Pandas seems to be helping me. So if I now want to calculate the output. Do I use "df" or "numpy_array"?

Comment: Whatever suits you. I just posted the way you could extract the numpy array if you need it. Given the fact that your dataset seems not to be labelled with a header (which is one of the really convenient tools of pandas), I would stuck to numpy I think.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is something like the following:

```py
import numpy as np


f = open("Data.txt", "r")

# Read the file, replace newline by "", split the string on commas
attributes = f.read().replace("\n", "").split(",")

# convert every element from string to float
attributes = np.array([float(element) for element in attributes])

# 20 random values in [-1,1)
w1 = 2 * np.random.random(20) - 1

def sigmoid(x):
    return 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))

outputs = sigmoid(np.dot(attributes, w1))

# Printing results
print(attributes)
print(w1)
print(outputs)
```

Comment: Alright, so now I got the errormessage: ValueError: shapes (21870,) and (20,) not aligned: 21870 (dim 0) != 20 (dim 0)

Comment: The code above is for a oneliner txt. Does your `Data.txt` file contain multiple lines ?

Comment: Yes it does, mayb that's my bad. Do you know how to edit the code for it to work with a .txt with multiple lines?

Comment: So you need a 2d array containing rows, each of which is constructed from each row of your txt file. Right?